# Launch using dedicated graphics card

Tags: nvidia-geforce

What exactly  'launch using dedicated graphics Card' does? I'm using low end Nvidia graphics Card and intel i3 processor and want to use the resources efficiently.I searched for the specifics of the options out of curiosity but couldn't find the details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What \*exactly\* does "Launch using dedicated graphics card" do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280847/what-exactly-does-launch-using-dedicated-graphics-card-do)

Answer (score 1):

I have answered this in detail https://askubuntu.com/a/1335604/1133973

> What exactly 'launch using dedicated graphics Card' does?

essentially it executes the same command with some specific environmental variables

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using that option makes the program run using your NVIDIA card instead of the intel integrated graphics. Differences in performance depend on your system configuration, though it is usually faster to use the NVIDIA card. However, you need to install the proprietary drivers from their [website](https://www.geforce.com/drivers)

Comment: It's actually better to install from either the Ubuntu software store or by using `apt`. Nvidia doesn't guarantee the website drivers will work with any particular distro.

Comment: (Also if the option is showing up, then the drivers are installed and working.)